# PySide2 Undo/Redo inside Maya

Tags: python, maya, pyside2, undo-redo

I have a question about PySide2 undo/redo in Maya. I read a discussions about using `undoInfo` Maya command but what if my GUI has to interact with many methods? How can I create an undo/redo for all of them at once instead of doing:

```
def method1():
    cmds.undoInfo(openChunk=True)
    # my code
    #
    cmds.undoInfo(closeChunk=True)

# or even
def method2():
    try
        cmds.undoInfo(openChunk=True)
        # my code
        #
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        cmds.undoInfo(closeChunk=True)
        
def method3():
    cmds.undoInfo(openChunk=True)
    # my code
    #
    cmds.undoInfo(closeChunk=True)
```

I want this:

```
cmds.undoInfo(openChunk=True)
def method1()
def method2()
def method3()
cmds.undoInfo(closeChunk=True)
```

Knowing that each method is connected to a button on the GUI

Comment: So, what you want is to *merge* commands, so that if you call an "undo" after that, it will automatically undo all those commands? That might be problematic, and would only be doable as long as you are **completely** sure that no other operation is done outside of your interface: if you call `method1()` and then do something from other components of the Maya UI, it would break the undo queue.

Comment: I can understand that. But let's say I create a GUI which rename objects inside Maya.
For both `maya.cmds` and `PySide2`  GUI the command is `cmds.rename("old_name", "new_name")`
If I rename objects whith the maya.cmds GUI and undo, it will do that once on all the objects BUT if I rename objects whith the PySide GUI, it will undo one object after another.
So my question is how to get PySide GUI act like a native maya GUI.
Thanks

Comment: As said (and as far as I can understand the API from the documentation), you can only do that ***if*** you are completely sure that **no other** command will be executed by the user outside of your interface. If you're using a modal dialog, that would probably be fine, if instead you're using normal UI elements, you cannot. So, is this the case?

Comment: Yes it's a normal window. So I'll implement an undo/redo for each method! Got no other choice! Thanks

Comment: Please, **be more precise**. A "normal window" is ***not*** a "modal dialog". A normal window allows using other windows in the program, a modal dialog (normally) doesn't. What you are asking can probably be done only in the second case.

Comment: I'm using a simple `QDialog` and to show it I use `show()` not `exec_()` or any other `windowFlags` which could change it to be `modal`. And I'll write a decorator which will set the `cmds.undoInfo()` on every method.

Comment: The decorator was the only solution I could suggest, indeed, but it'll just simplify the coding, and won't result in what you're asking for multiple commands. Unfortunately, if the dialog is not modal, you cannot achieve "grouping" of undo commands: there could be some level of work around, like closing the current "chunk" when the window loses focus, but that might not be effective (the user might just be switching temporarily to another program) nor safe (like using UI elements that don't cause focus switching or commands triggered by keyboard shortcuts).